# Apply different start parameters to model using purrr::map within dplyr::mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, tidyverse

Trying to answer someones question on the ggplot2 mailing list and I can't figure it out:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/YgCqQX8JbPM

OP wants to apply different start parameters to subsets of his data for the nls model. My thoughts were that he should read up on dplyr and purrr, but after a few hours of trying myself I've hit a wall. Unsure if it's a bug or my lack of experience with purrr.

```
library(tidyverse)

# input dataset
df <- data.frame(Group = c(rep("A", 7), rep("B", 7), rep("C", 7)),
                 Time = c(rep(c(1:7), 3)),
                 Result = c(100, 96.9, 85.1, 62.0, 30.7, 15.2, 9.6, 
                            10.2, 14.8, 32.26, 45.85, 56.25, 70.1, 100,
                            100, 55.61, 3.26, -4.77, -7.21, -3.2, -5.6))

# nest the datasets for computing models
df_p <-
df %>%
group_by(Group) %>%
nest

# add model parameters as rows/columns
df_p$starta = c(-3, 4,-3)
df_p$startb = c(85, 85, 85)
df_p$startc = c(4, 4, 4)
df_p$startd = c(10,10,10)

# compute models using nls
df_p %>%
mutate(model2 = map(data, ~nls(Result ~ a+(b-a)/(1+(Time/c)^d), data = ., start = c(a = starta, b = startb, c = startc, d = startd)))
        )

#Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
#  parameters without starting value in 'data': a, b, d
```

Feels related to this bug, but this has been fixed for a while now...
https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1447

From what I can tell, it's looking for the variables in the scope of the nested tibble, but I want it to be in the scope of the mutate call. I don't know if there is a way around this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The example data is tricky because Group B basically has time in reverse. Finding good initial values for that is not my problem. So I made up new data for Group B. Here's how to set up a data frame in order to apply `nls()` inside of `map2()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(Group = c(rep("A", 7), rep("B", 7), rep("C", 7)),
                 Time = c(rep(c(1:7), 3)),
                 Result = c(100, 96.9, 85.1, 62.0, 30.7, 15.2, 9.6, 
                            ## I replaced these values!!
                            ## Group B initial values are NOT MY PROBLEM
                            105, 90, 82, 55, 40, 23, 7, 
                            100, 55.61, 3.26, -4.77, -7.21, -3.2, -5.6))

## ggplot(df, aes(x = Time, y = Result, group = Group)) + geom_line()

df_p <-
  df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  nest() %>% 
  ## init vals are all the same, but this shows how to make them different
  mutate(start = list(
    list(a = -3, b = 85, c = 4, d = 10),
    list(a = -3, b = 85, c = 4, d = 10),
    list(a = -3, b = 85, c = 4, d = 10)
  )

)

df_p %>%
  mutate(model2 = map2(data, start,
                       ~ nls(Result ~ a+(b-a)/(1+(Time/c)^d),
                             data = .x, start = .y)))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>    Group             data      start    model2
#>   <fctr>           <list>     <list>    <list>
#> 1      A <tibble [7 × 2]> <list [4]> <S3: nls>
#> 2      B <tibble [7 × 2]> <list [4]> <S3: nls>
#> 3      C <tibble [7 × 2]> <list [4]> <S3: nls>
```

Comment: Indeed, not your problem, nor mine with the parameters themselves. One question is how you're referencing the list columns as .x and .y. How did you know to do that? Why not .data and .start?

Comment: The placeholders when you use purrr's formula shortcut for defining the to-be-mapped function are always `.x` (`map_*()` variants) or `.x` and `.y`  (`map2_*()` variants. That's in the `purrr::map()` help file, for example.

Comment: If you use `pmap()`, you can rely on argument names in your custom function. The formula shortcut is no longer relevant in that case. You could define `myfun <- function(.data, .start) nls(Result ~ a+(b-a)/(1+(Time/c)^d), data = .data, start = .start)`. Then make sure you use those exact variable names and only those variables in the data frame you plan as primary input to `pmap(select(df, .data, .start), myfun)`.

Answer (score 2):

Not able to find the a set of parameters to produce the models you set up, but I think this is what you can do as far as setting up the model fitting process; Basically you can wrap all the parameters `starta, startb .. etc` into the data as well as the `Result` and `Time` columns, and then you can access the parameters with `.$`, notice in this case you will need the `unique` function to pick one value as the value has been broadcasted when unnesting. With a straightforward model formula, `a + b*Time`, it produces the models in the `model2` column, you may follow this route and tweak the initial parameters passed to `nls` to fit a more complicated formula as you have specified:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_p %>% unnest %>% group_by(Group) %>% nest %>%
         mutate(model2 = map(data, ~nls(Result ~ a + b*Time, data = ., 
                                        start = c(a = unique(.$starta), 
                                                  b = unique(.$startb))
                                       )
                             )
               )

# A tibble: 3 × 3
#   Group             data    model2
#  <fctr>           <list>    <list>
#1      A <tibble [7 × 6]> <S3: nls>
#2      B <tibble [7 × 6]> <S3: nls>
#3      C <tibble [7 × 6]> <S3: nls>
```